# Does Blender 2.8 use floating point?

Tags: modeling, units, measurement

I've heard a lot of people say it does, but 'where' does it say that it uses that. If it does, is there a way to switch it to something a little more precise (because occasionally floating point may encounter rounding errors.)

Comment: There is no precise number in Blender for now AFAIK. Most of the value use float 32 as number in Python 3.7.0. There are some workaround method that can hold decimal number, but not fully support.

Comment: And Blender is not aim for CAD system, so the issue won't be *fix* in Blender for further build. Unless there is a new development project